# What is the Taxonomy of Python?

Tags: python, class, module, package, taxonomy

I am new to Python and come from a background in R.
I am trying to get a handle on the taxonomy on Python, and google is no help.
Here is a chart - have I visualized it properly?
My big hurdle is what to call the collection of components in a module. Should they be referred to as functions? methods? classes? functions, methods and classes?

[image]

Comment: Simply, a module contains _functions_, _classes_ and _variables_. There are more complex ways of describing this, but the base idea of importing a module to get a handy collection of callable functions and variables should be enough from what you're asking. See: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm

Comment: Attributes/members/names? Modules contain references to objects, those objects could be classes, functions, anything

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see now that there are a collection of objects in the orange band of the chart. Since my priority is on using precise language,  I will specifically reference the type of object -  like class (like KBinsDiscretizer) or a loader (like fetch_lfw_people), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this link to skim through for the relevant areas you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Essentially everything in Python is an object with a name that is assigned/defined value.

Comment: Thanks @InhirCode this is incredibly helpful. I am sure I will reference it frequently for a while.